# Why are FQDN (ending with a dot) not working in CSP?

Tags: fqdn, content-security-policy

I have a FQDN in my CSP:

The source list for the Content Security Policy directive 'img-src' contains an invalid source: 'xxx.de.'. It will be ignored.

This is my csp:

```
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
'unsafe-eval' www.xxx.de; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
font-src 'self' data:; img-src 'self' xxx.de.; frame-src 'self' 
www.youtube-nocookie.com xxx.de;
```

Why are domains having a dot at the end not allowed in CSP?

I need to link to this URL, and I need to have a CSP, this is my current CSP, the spec does not appear to allow me to describe the URL I have, how can I work around this?

Comment: "Why are domains having a dot at the end not allowed in CSP?" — What sort of answer are you looking for here? You're unlikely to get anything beyond "Because the spec says so" or guesses about what was going through the spec designers' heads.

Comment: I was guessing what was going throu the spec designers' head. Yes.

Comment: Then, as pointed out, that's a matter of opinion and off-topic.

Comment: I do not see how this is a matter of opinion. I mean it is a real-world-problem. It is a real-world error-message.

Comment: That it is an error message is a fact. That the spec doesn't allow a `.` there is a fact. That the spec saying that is the cause of the error message is a fact. Why the spec was written that way probably isn't recorded anywhere, questions asking why invite *speculation* about what the spec designers were thinking (i.e. are unlikely to be answered with facts), and isn't a problem of any kind.

Comment: Well, its my problem. I can neither reference https://upload.wikimedia.org./wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/2006-02-13_Drop_before_impact.jpg/396px-2006-02-13_Drop_before_impact.jpg in the img-src-attribute nor change the url nor remove the csp-directive. I can not display that image. Thats a concrete problem.

Comment: Knowing why the designers of the spec designed it that way won't help you solve that problem though.

Comment: Just use https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/2006-02-13_Drop_before_impact.jpg/396px-2006-02-13_Drop_before_impact.jpg as the URL instead.

Comment: I said "(...) nor change the url(...)". I think if the w3 resolve this mistake it will guide browser-developers (developers who develop browsers like mozilla, chrome, safari) to change the browser's csp validation.

Comment: Then you should look at removing the barrier preventing you from changing code on the website you control the CSP for. Odds are it'll be easier and faster than changing the spec and getting every browser to update to the new rules.

Comment: I noticed that you might think the spec is wrong? I agree. Still a bad question? :P

Comment: "I noticed that you might think the spec is wrong?" — No. You noticed me noticing that the spec did not allow you to do what you want.

Comment: What I did? I did not use the url having a dot at the end of the hostname, others did.

Comment: And yes. Still a bad question. See [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Quote: *Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced.*. Bad question: "Why is the spec like this?". Better question: "I need to link to *this URL*, and I need to have a CSP, this is my current CSP, the spec does not appear to allow me to describe the URL I have, how can I work around this?"

Comment: The answer is clear: Because csp do not allow a dot at the end of the hostname. Question solved, problem remains unchanged.

Comment: For security reasons I need to keep that . at the end of the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec is simply wrong. A dot as the last character of the domain should be allowed.

Comment: I do not see any downvote in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77107092/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) (at the time of my comment). But while I agree the spec is inconvenient, would [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77007729/6309) be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: @VonC I had a downvote seconds ago. And no, the IP of the Server running your Flask app differs from the browsers IP. In order to recognize the session in wikimedia, the IP address must be the same.

Comment: Good point. I have edited the answer to provide an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

Because the specs say so.

The [host-source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#grammardef-host-source):

> `host-source = [ scheme-part "://" ] host-part [ ":" port-part ] [ path-part ]`

requires a [host-part](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#grammardef-host-part):

> `host-part   = "*" / [ "*." ] 1*host-char *( "." 1*host-char )`

which has to end with a [host-char](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#grammardef-host-char):

> `host-char   = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-"`

… which cannot be a `.`.

The path-part:

> `path-part   = path-absolute (but not including ";" or ",")`
> ; path-absolute is defined in section 3.3 of RFC 3986.

is [defined elsewhere](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> `path-absolute   ; begins with "/" but not "//"`

… which has to start with `/` so cannot consist entirely of `.`.

Comment: You explain that a dot is not allowed. But why is a dot not allowed?

Comment: @Grim — What I asked what sort of answer you were looking for and suggested a couple of possible answers,  your response was "Do the specs say so?". They do. That is your answer. Speculation as to what the designers of the specification were thinking is a matter of opinion and off-topic here.

Comment: Then this might be a mistake inside the spec.

Comment: See, `do the spec say so?` was more like a comment. The genuine question is `Why are domains having a dot at the end not allowed in CSP?` from the question. I know, many questions are answered in comments very well. Many bad questions are written in comments. My intention was to make the bounty on the question. After the bounty was set, I commented a question if the spec say so. Since I am not time traveling, and the bounty was set before the question in the comment the bounty is on the genuine question.

Comment: Anyway, I deleted my comment, sorry for that. It was obviously misleading. Was my mistake.

Comment: Then I repeat: What sort of answer are you looking for? I've suggested two possibilities. One is off topic. The other is this answer. Is there a third kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: Well there might be something like, "yes, its a specification mistake" or "find domains are bad practice said iab" or "browser is not allowed to look behind find domains for sandbox reasons" or "csp is dicouraging such domains" or "find domains are checked in cors only" or something else. Idk.

Comment: Please review the answer since the spec changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my problem:
>
> ```
> https://upload.wikimedia.org./wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/2006-02-13_Drop_before_impact.jpg/396px-2006-02-13_Drop_before_impact.jpg 
>                            ^^^
> ```
>
> I can neither reference it in the `img-src-attribute` nor change the URL nor remove the `csp-directive`. I can not display that image.

You have a unique situation where the URL you need to allow through your CSP contains a trailing dot in the domain name, and CSP does not support such syntax.
Since you cannot change the URL or remove the CSP, you are essentially locked into a scenario where the standard tools at your disposal are not sufficient.

Given these constraints, one approach would be to create a server-side proxy that fetches the image from the FQDN with the trailing dot and then serves it under your own domain. Your server-side code could make an HTTP request to the original URL, fetch the image, and then serve it as a response to a request to a URL on your own domain.
That way, you can add your own domain to the [`img-src` directive in your CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src), and you are in compliance with the CSP specifications.

For example, in a [Python Flask app](https://flask.palletsprojects.com), a simple proxy endpoint might look like this:

```py
import requests
from flask import Flask, Response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/proxy_image/<path:subpath>')
def proxy_image(subpath):
    base_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org./wikipedia/commons/"
    target_url = f"{base_url}{subpath}"
    
    response = requests.get(target_url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return Response(response.content, content_type=response.headers['Content-Type'])
    else:
        return Response(f"Unable to fetch image. Status code: {response.status_code}", status=response.status_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then you could update your CSP to allow images from your own domain:

```
img-src 'self' your-domain.com;
```

That will allow you to display the image without modifying the original URL or removing the CSP directive.

---

> The IP of the Server running your Flask app differs from the browsers IP.
> In order to recognize the session in Wikimedia, the IP address must be the same.

If Wikimedia enforces IP-based session restrictions, then a server-side proxy solution will not work because it makes requests from the server's IP address, not the client's IP address.

An alternative approach could be to use a service worker in the client's browser to intercept requests to URLs with the problematic domain and redirect them to the correct URL without the trailing dot. That would preserve the client's IP address.

You would need to:

- Register a service worker in your web app.
- Inside the service worker, listen for `fetch` events.
- If a fetch event is for a URL that matches the problematic domain with the trailing dot, alter the URL to remove the trailing dot before making the network request.

For example, `service-worker.js`, in the public directory of your web server:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  
  if (url.hostname === 'upload.wikimedia.org.') {
    const newUrl = url.toString().replace('upload.wikimedia.org.', 'upload.wikimedia.org');
    event.respondWith(fetch(newUrl));
  }
});
```

That script is listening for fetch events with `self.addEventListener`. It checks if the hostname matches 'upload.wikimedia.org.' (with the trailing dot).

- If it matches, we create a `newUrl` string where we have replaced the hostname with 'upload.wikimedia.org' (without the trailing dot).
- We then call `event.respondWith(fetch(newUrl))` to make a network request to the new URL and respond with that.

Register the service worker in the main JavaScript file of your web application. This would go in a script that runs on your page load:

```js
// main.js (or another appropriate file)
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
      .then((registration) => {
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
      }, (err) => {
        console.error('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
      });
  });
}
```

And make sure that the script where you registered the service worker is included in your HTML file. If your script is in a file called `main.js`, it might look something like this:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- ... other head elements ... -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- ... your body content ... -->

  <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The second approach looks good, Ill try this. I guess, if a browser support CSP then it also support SW. I am not sure if every browser support the `console`-object. I need to test this because the CSP might prevent the call of the fetch-event in the service-worker.